# How to close folders that in use by Explorer as it uninstallers do

Tags: vb.net

I know most uninstallers of programs (at least since Windows 7) could delete program folder even if it opened up in Explorer. After uninstalling Explorer just refreshes and go up to Program Files folder automatically.

How to do same thing (tell explorer that folder need to be not in use) in programming language (particularly in VB.net)?

Comment: `Directory.Delete("C:\Program Files\MyFolder", True)`?  I don't think there is anything special you need to do, but the application will probably have to be run as administrator in order to delete folders under Program Files (UAC).

Comment: @Mark, Sorry, I need to clarify question: my goal is not to delete folder, but invoke same behavior: make explorer go to upper folder as like folder does not exist anymore (while it does).

Comment: If I understand you, if a folder is open in explorer and selected in the tree view, and you delete that folder programmatically, you want the selected folder to change to the parent folder? Not sure about previous versions, but this behaviour happens automatically in Windows 10 Build 1703. Just checked it.

Comment: @DavidWilson, I've updated question, see my previous comment. I'm actually don't want to delete file. Just "free" it from use by explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So you want explorer to  go to the parent folder of the current folder. If the current folder is "c:\windows\fonts", you want to change it to "c:\windows".

The following code should do this.. Have a look at the comments for an explanation of some of the code

```
    Private Sub ChangeExplorerToParentFolderOf(currentFolder As String)
    Dim shellWindows As SHDocVw.ShellWindows = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim filename As String
    Dim operationCompleted As Boolean = False
    currentFolder = "file:///" & currentFolder.Replace("\", "/").ToLower
    'Searches all open explorer windows that are pointing to
    'the currentFolder parameter and if found, navigates to
    'its parent folder.
    '
    'if successful, sets the operationCompleted cariable to true
    For Each ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer In shellWindows
        filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName).ToLower()
        If filename.Contains("explorer") And ie.LocationURL.ToString.ToLower = currentFolder Then
            Dim parentFolder As String = currentFolder.Remove(currentFolder.LastIndexOf("/"))
            ie.Navigate2(parentFolder)
            operationCompleted = True
        End If
    Next
    'If no instance of explorer is pointing to the currentFolder (operationCompleted=false),
    'show a messagebox to say so
    If operationCompleted = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("No instance of Windows Explorer exists that" & vbCrLf & "points to " & currentFolder)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it didn't worked for me. [https://i.imgur.com/AN6dE85.png](https://i.imgur.com/AN6dE85.png)

Comment: Duh sorry. For some reason I managed to paste code that wasnt the final answer. I've updated it.